# Docker Compose Airflow HA 502 Server Error for http+docker://localhost/version: Bad Gateway ("b'Bad response from Docker engine'")

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, rabbitmq, airflow

I installed airflow in local, using MySQL, celery executor, and rabbitmq

now I install airflow in the docker to set up Airflow HA Scheduler with YAML file:

```
version: '3'
x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
  image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-apache/airflow:2.3.4}
  environment:
    &airflow-common-env
    AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: CeleryExecutor

  # AIRFLOW__DATABASE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
  # AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
  # AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
  # AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL: redis://:@redis:6379/0
  # AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: ''
  # AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: 'true'
  # AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: 'true'
  # AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKENDS: 'airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth'
  # _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ${_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS:-}

    AIRFLOW__DATABASE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: mysql://airflow:password@localhost/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: mysql://airflow:password@localhost/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: db+mysql://airflow:password@localhost:3306/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL: pyamqp://airflow:password@localhost:5672/myvhost
    AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: 'LgPLCqY0vrVDAI7s7eR408ZfRNm_CekdALmA1CJtYgs='
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: 'false'
    AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKENDS: 'airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth'
    _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ${_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS:-}
  volumes:
    - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
  user: "${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:0"
  depends_on:
    &airflow-common-depends-on
    rabbitmq:
      condition: service_healthy
    mysql:
      condition: service_healthy

services:
#  postgres:
#    image: postgres:13
#    environment:
#      POSTGRES_USER: airflow
#      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: airflow
#      POSTGRES_DB: airflow
#    volumes:
#      - postgres-db-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
#    healthcheck:
#      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "airflow"]
#      interval: 5s
#      retries: 5
#    restart: always
    
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: airflowdb
      MYSQL_USER: airflow
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    volumes:
      - mysql-db-volume:/var/lib/mysql/airflowdb
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin" ,"ping", "-h", "localhost"]
      interval: 5s
      retries: 5
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    restart: always

  # redis:
  #   image: redis:latest
  #   expose:
  #     - 6379
  #   healthcheck:
  #     test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
  #     interval: 5s
  #     timeout: 30s
  #     retries: 50
  #   restart: always

  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.9
    container_name: rabbitmq
    ports:
      - 5672:5672
      - 15672:15672
    volumes:
      - ~/.docker-conf/rabbitmq/data/:/var/lib/rabbitmq/
      - ~/.docker-conf/rabbitmq/log/:/var/log/rabbitmq
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:15672"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    networks:
      - rabbitmq_go_net

volumes:
# postgres-db-volume:
  mysql-db-volume:
```

To deploy Airflow on Docker Compose, I fetch file from airflow [docker-compose](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/docker-compose/index.html#fetching-docker-compose-yaml) then edit environment to the same airflow.config (`sql_alchemy, reesult_backend, broker`) and mysql, rabbitmq instead of postgres, redis.

when I run `docker-compose up airflow-init` get error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 268, in _raise_for_status
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "/home/linhnq/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 1022, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 502 Server Error: Bad Gateway for url: http+docker://localhost/version

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 214, in _retrieve_server_version
    return self.version(api_version=False)["ApiVersion"]
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/api/daemon.py", line 181, in version
    return self._result(self._get(url), json=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 274, in _result
    self._raise_for_status(response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 270, in _raise_for_status
    raise create_api_error_from_http_exception(e)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/errors.py", line 31, in create_api_error_from_http_exception
    raise cls(e, response=response, explanation=explanation)
docker.errors.APIError: 502 Server Error for http+docker://localhost/version: Bad Gateway ("b'Bad response from Docker engine'")

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/docker-compose", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('docker-compose==1.29.2', 'console_scripts', 'docker-compose')())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 81, in main
    command_func()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 200, in perform_command
    project = project_from_options('.', options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/cli/command.py", line 60, in project_from_options
    return get_project(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/cli/command.py", line 152, in get_project
    client = get_client(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 41, in get_client
    client = docker_client(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 170, in docker_client
    client = APIClient(use_ssh_client=not use_paramiko_ssh, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 197, in __init__
    self._version = self._retrieve_server_version()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 221, in _retrieve_server_version
    raise DockerException(
docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: 502 Server Error for http+docker://localhost/version: Bad Gateway ("b'Bad response from Docker engine'")
```

how can I fix this error?
thanks,`